# Require macros from the same file in another macro

Tags: hy

In the following code, given that `hy` seem to give a `NameError` when not explicitly requiring a macro's dependent macros, how do I require a macro in the same file in another macro?

```
(defmacro with-cwd [#* body] `(do ~@body))
(defmacro let-cwd [vars #* body] `(let ~vars (with-cwd ~@body)))
```

In a package called `oreo`, in a file called `oreo.hy`, I tried the following methods using `(require oreo.oreo [with-cwd])`, and none worked:

```
(defmacro let-cwd [vars #* body] (require oreo.oreo [with-cwd]) `(let ~vars (with-cwd ~@body)))

(defmacro let-cwd [vars #* body] `(let ~vars (require oreo.oreo [with-cwd]) (with-cwd ~@body)))

(defmacro let-cwd [vars #* body] `(let ~vars ~(require oreo.oreo [with-cwd]) (with-cwd ~@body)))

(defmacro let-cwd [vars #* body] `(do (require oreo.oreo [with-cwd]) (let ~vars (with-cwd ~@body))))

(defmacro let-cwd [vars #* body] `(do ~(require oreo.oreo [with-cwd]) (let ~vars (with-cwd ~@body))))
```

UPDATE: Upon request, I have modified the code to the point where the original problem still remains, but the code itself is significantly shorter.

Comment: First, simplify. You have a lot of code that isn't related to the essential thing you're asking about.

Comment: Will my current edit suffice?

Comment: I tried this with the 4th version in your second code block and it seems to behave correctly. Try writing out your exact reproduction steps, using shell commands. If the result isn't an error message but it still isn't what you expected, explain why you expected something different.

Comment: Alright, so, using the master `hy` branch, I put `with-cwd` and the 4th version of `let-cwd` in `test.hy`, then put `(require test [let-cwd]); (let-cwd [ string "Hello!" ] (print string))` (replacing the semicolon with a newline) in `test2.hy`, then ran `hy test2.hy`. The output is a `NameError: name 'with_cwd' is not defined` error.

Comment: I get `Hello!` when I try that on my machine. Perhaps you're not running the version of Hy that you think you are.

Comment: I installed `hy` using `pip install https://github.com/hylang/hy/archive/master.tar.gz`; the `repl` header states `Hy unknown using CPython(main) 3.10.4 on Linux`.

Comment: Well this is interesting... When you had first commented, I had commented out the last implementation and added the `require` to a new declaration; when I ran `hy test2.hy`, it errored out with a `NameError`. Then I commented out the test itself, ran the file, and nothing happened, obviously. However, when I uncommented again, I got `Hello!` this time, as expected the first time. Is there some sort of caching going on here? This happened with my official tests as well.

Comment: Presumably. See https://docs.hylang.org/en/master/semantics.html#when-bytecode-is-regenerated

Comment: And that perfectly answers my second question. Thanks for all the help! Should I post the answer, or will you?

Comment: You can do it. ~~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fourth version works, as noted by [Kodiologist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1451346/kodiologist) in their comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73084195/require-macros-from-the-same-file-in-another-macro?noredirect=1#comment129093172_73084195); the final versions of two test files are therefore:

```
;; a.hy
(defmacro with-cwd [#* body] `(do ~@body))
(defmacro let-cwd [vars #* body] `(do (require oreo.oreo [with-cwd]) (let ~vars (with-cwd ~@body))))
```

And:

```
;; b.hy
(require a [let-cwd])
(let-cwd [ string "Hello!" ] (print string))
```

The second file then outputs `Hello!`.