# Requiring `hy' macro with `raise' function triggers `raise' on `require'

Tags: hy

When trying to `require` the following macro in another file, the `raise` seems to be triggering immediately:

```
(defmacro assert [a [b True] [message None]]
    `(unless (= ~a ~b) (raise (AssertionError (or ~message ~a)))))
```

This results in an `AssertionError: True`.

Steps to reproduce (sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't):

```
echo '(defmacro assert [a [b True] [message None]] `(unless (= ~a ~b) (raise (AssertionError (or ~message ~a)))))' > a.hy
echo '(require a [assert])' > b.hy
echo '(assert True)' >> b.hy
hy b.hy
```

Comment: (1) Giving a macro the same name as a core macro is a bad idea unless you know what you're doing. (2) Like I said in my comment on your previous question, when you want to talk about a problem that involves multiple files, provide complete and exact reproduction steps as a sequence of shell commands (use lines like `echo '(my-code)' > file.hy` to set the contents of each file). (3) Simplify! I bet you can figure this one out yourself if you simplify it one step at a time.

Comment: I can't seem to isolate what the problem is; sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. I've updated my question, but I don't how else to simplify the code.

Comment: If the problem occurs inconsistently, it's probably related to bytecode caching, as in your previous question. Investigate by setting `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` or deleting `__pycache__` manually.

Comment: For some reason, it seems to work if I replace `unless (= ~a ~b)` with `if (not (= ~a ~b))`; there's not supposed to be a difference there, right? And on a side note, the `pytest` doesn't seem to work either, though individual tests succeed when running them manually with `hy`.

Comment: Good work, you're 90% of the way there. Since you now understand that `unless` is the culprit, try looking up its documentation. Or, simplify some more. Does `unless` work like you expect in a one-line example program?

Comment: ... Is this an issue where the `NameErrors` for macros are superseded by other errors again? This is becoming a little confusing... I'd thought `unless` had been integrated into the `hy` core. Ah, well. The pytest is still an issue, but I feel that's a problem with my plugin; I'm always getting an `INTERNALERROR`. Either way, thanks for all the help! I'll answer the question, then?

Comment: "Is this an issue where the `NameErrors` for macros are superseded by other errors again?" — Right. Python evaluates the arguments before the function name. "I'd thought `unless` had been integrated into the hy core." — No, it started out there, but I moved it to Hyrule a little over a year ago.

Comment: Right; makes sense. I'll just add an answer with the context then!

Answer (score 1):

In another instance of Python evaluating function arguments before names, as stated by [Kodiologist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1451346/kodiologist) in their comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73164742/requiring-hy-macro-with-raise-function-triggers-raise-on-require?noredirect=1#comment129240573_73164742) and [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73050869/10827766) on one of my previous questions ["Non-existent hy macros runs assertions, but fails appropriately with everything else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73045601/non-existent-hy-macros-runs-assertions-but-fails-appropriately-with-everything), the issue was that `unless` didn't trigger a `NameError` when it didn't exist, since it was moved from the `hy` core to `hyrule` a little over a year ago.